# Does CloudFront drop Origin response body when the response code is an error for which a Custom Error Response was set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'll preface this by saying that in my case the answer appears to be **no**, however I might have misconfigured my setup and cannot find mention of this anywhere in the documentation, so I'd like to know how it is expected to work.

When defining a Custom Error Response, you choose the Error Code from the Origin, the response page to return, and the error code to replace the one at the Origin.

Normally this works as expected - say for example I set up CloudFront to return "error.html" with code 404 when the Origin provides a 403. When probing for a link I know should return a 403, I receive "error.html" with 404.
Unfortunately, it seems that when the Origin provides it's own body (I've seen this happen with a JSON as well as an HTML page), CloudFront only replaces the headers - the error code switches correctly from 403 to 404, but the body is the one sent by Origin - "error.html" is not provided.

Is this the expected behavior? Does the documentation mention this anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not expected.

Configuring a custom error page and a custom response code should replace the *entire* response with the custom response -- headers and body -- along with the custom status code -- including *none* of the original response headers or body.

In the event of a second error occurring -- that is, an error encountered by CloudFront during the actual fetching the custom error document -- both the code and body will be whatever the origin provided during that second request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html

You might check the response headers, particularly the `Age` header, to verify that you aren't getting a cached response much older than you expect.  Changing the custom error page configuration doesn't invalidate any already-cached error responses.

Cross-check the CloudFront logs with the origin logs to verify that what you're seeing is indeed live.

Note also that none of the above is applicable to the error responses from the "hidden" CloudFront distribution associated with an edge-optimized API Gateway endpoint,  nor with Lambda@Edge customization of error responses.